# C#.NET Deserialize JSON string to object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize JSON into an object "MarginBalance".   When i try to deserialize this JSON:

```
{"totalValue":"0.00091979","pl":"0.00000000","lendingFees":"0.00000000","netValue":"0.00091979","totalBorrowedValue":"0.00000000","currentMargin":"1.00000000"}
```

to this object:

```
public class MarginBalance : IMarginBalance
{ 
    [JsonProperty("totalValue")]
    public double TotalValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pl")]
    public double PL { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lendingFees")]
    public double LendingFees { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("netValue")]
    public double NetValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("totalBorrowedValue")]
    public double TotalBorrowedValue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currentMargin")]
    public double CurrentMargin { get; set; }
}
```

implementing this Interface:

```
public interface IMarginBalance
{
    double TotalValue { get; } 
    double PL { get; } 
    double LendingFees { get; } 
    double NetValue { get; } 
    double TotalBorrowedValue { get; } 
    double CurrentMargin { get; }
}
```

it returns null.  Here is my deserialization code:

```
var postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var data = PostData<IDictionary<string, MarginBalance>>("returnMarginAccountSummary", postData);
if (data != null)
{
    // never reaches here 
    var returnData = new Dictionary<string, IMarginBalance>();
    foreach (string key in data.Keys)
    {
        returnData.Add(key, data[key]);
    }
    return returnData;
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private T PostData<T>(string command, Dictionary<string, object> postData)
{
    return ApiWebClient.PostData<T>(command, postData);
} 

public T PostData<T>(string command, Dictionary<string, object> postData)
{
    postData.Add("command", command);
    postData.Add("nonce", Helper.GetCurrentHttpPostNonce());

    var jsonString = PostString(Helper.ApiUrlHttpsRelativeTrading, postData.ToHttpPostString());
    var output = JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);

    return output;
}
```

Hopefully someone can work it out!  I have been trying all day... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us more code. How do you do the deserialization?

Comment: @dotctor i have updated my question

Comment: change `JsonSerializer.DeserializeObject` to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`

Comment: @dotctor when i changed to JsonConvert i received this error : An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting value "0.00091977" to type 'Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.MarginBalance'. Path 'totalValue', line 1, position 26.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in the Json are surrounded by apostrophes, meaning they are strings, not numbers. You can try to either remove the apostrophes from the numbers in the Json string, or change the field types form double to string in the object.

The `JsonProperty` attributes you used in `MarginBalance` belong to `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization` namespace. To deserialize the object you should use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarginBalance>(jsonString)`

Comment: I tried that and received An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting value "0.00091977" to type 'Jojatekok.PoloniexAPI.WalletTools.MarginBalance'. Path 'totalValue', line 1, position 26.

Comment: @Nickmccomb You're still deserialising as `IDictionary<string, MarginBalance>`. Don't do that if you've only got one single `MarginBalance`.

Comment: The numbers in the Json are surrounded by apostrophes, meaning they are strings, not numbers. You can try to either remove the apostrophes from the numbers in the Json string, or change the field types form double to string in the object.

Comment: @hvd - Yeah i think that's it too, just changing my code and i'll mark your answer as complete if it works :)

Comment: @hvd That was it, thanks for that!  can you write that as an answer and i'll mark it as the solution please.  Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Nickmccomb This answer already had `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarginBalance>` in it (just not readable before I edited it, but it was there), so I think it's okay to just accept this answer. :)

Comment: That edit does not look good... There should be no problem deserialising strings as numbers if they are in the right format.